# Define custom title for calendar pages in MiddleMan

Tags: ruby, middleman

I've just set up a small static blog using `middleman` 3 and `middleman-blogging` gems, and am currently polishing everything. I was looking at my pages from a SEO point of view, and noticed all my calendar pages display the same title (which is quite bad for SEO, afaik).

Currently, I use this to generate the title tag in my layout (Slim template engine) :

```
title
  | #{current_article.title unless current_article.nil?} 
  | #{ " | " unless current_article.nil?}
  | My blog name
```

For articles, it's quite easy as I just need to define the title in the frontmatter, but I obviously can't go this way for my dynamically generated calendar pages. Unless I can use variables in the frontmatter of calendar.slim, but I couldn't get anything working so far. Maybe through the `config.rb` file ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, here's how I chose to proceed : in my calendar.slim and tag.slim templates, I simply defined a `@title` variable that I use in my default layout. In `calendar.slim`, I use the built-in variables `year`, `month` and `day` to build a title string, and in `tag.slim`, I use the built-in `tagname` variable.

```
[calendar.slim]

- case page_type
- when 'month'
  - date = date_to_fr Date.new(year, month, 1).strftime('%B %Y')
- when 'year'
  - date = year

- @title = "#{date} - Archives"

(...)
```

And then in the layout, I then use the following code to display my `@title` variable followed by my blog name, unless `@title` does not exist (then I just use my blog name as the page title) :

```
[layout.slim]

title 
      = "#{@title} | " unless @title.nil?
      | Pierre-Adrien Buisson : Le Blog !
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `year`, `month`, and `day` variables set which you can use. You can also use frontmatter in your calendar template the same way you do anywhere else (`current_resource.data`), and you can access the articles for that calendar page in `articles` and loop through them to pull data out of each one. Lots and lots of options.

The default generated `calendar.html.erb` has examples of using these.

Comment: Well yes, but actually I wanted to use in the layout some data coming from the actual page (the calendar template, for instance). See my answer for the (not so elegant) solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

Just building on [pabuisson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22673078/1166181).

You can't set frontmatter variables dynamically.

```
current_page.data.foo = true
current_page.data.too #=> nil
```

And frontmatter isn't templated

```
---
title: <%= "foo" %>
---
<%= current_page.data.title %> == <%%= "foo" %>
```

So what I did was in my layouts I checked for instance variables first, then fell back to frontmatter.

```
<title><%= @title || current_page.data.title %></title>
```

This way I can set most of my variables in the frontmatter, but when I need a dynamic variable I can use an instance variable.